# Not able to call factory method after including factory function with $provide.factory in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

```
app.config(['$controllerProvider','$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide',function($controllerProvider,
        $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {
        app.register = {
          controller: $controllerProvider.register,
          directive: $compileProvider.directive,
          filter: $filterProvider.register,
          factory: $provide.factory,
          service: $provide.service
        };
      }
]);

app.controller('myCntrl', ['$scope', function($s) {
   app.register.factory('customFactory',[customFactory]);
   customFactory.init();
 });
```

**factory.js**

```
function customFactory(){
    var c= {};
    c.init = function(){
        console.log('init function');
    }
    return c;
}
```

Here I will be adding factory.js file in runtime and I now need to inject custom factory in my controller. So I have used **$provide.factory** method for it. But, I am not able to call **init()** function inside **customFactory**

Comment: Monkey patching AngularJS to allow adding items to the injector during the run phase is not recommended practice. It makes the code difficult to understand, debug, test, and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the controller that dynamically registers `customFactory`, the `customFactory` name binding is just a function. To call `init()` at the location you've noted, you'll need to invoke `customFactory` as a function.

```
customFactory().init();
```

However, if you've got another recipe elsewhere (e.g. controller) which needs to depend on `customFactory`, then you can access `init()` as you might expect.

```
app.controller('anotherCtrl', ['customFactory', function (customFactory) {
    customFactory.init();  // OK!
}]);
```

When `customFactory` gets registered, the AngularJS dependency injector knows how to create it as a singleton and subsequently you can just access it as a value.